# Js not loading after merge : magento

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I have a problem with magento merge Js.

I have merged the Js files but now it is not loading the Js files that are merged.

If i tried to access it gives internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

As always with magento try flushing the cache or turning the cache off while you are developing

in backend go to 
System > Configuration > cache management

Then flush the Magento cache / and flush cache storage.

then disable the cache for everything and that should alleviate some headaches with stuff being cached.

remember to turn it back on when you put it to production though.